How Debezium SQL Server works under the hood
I've been looking on how the connector of Debezium for SQL Server works under the hood, but I'm not sure I've understood it correctly.
In the docs, in the section about the snapshots (see https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html), it says


Read the maximum log sequence number (LSN) position in the server’s transaction log.


How does it read the LSN is not clear to me. Does it read it on the file level or from the server, by querying it with sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn() ? This query is called with a frequency as set in the polling parameter?
Thanks

You'd have to ask the Debezium developers, not here. LSN can be read in a lot of ways, for example with help of FN_DBLOG.

debezium-connector-sqlserver is open source and hosted on Github. Have you tried looking at the source code?

Based on the "read the source" comment, I found this which sure suggests that fn_cdc_get_max_lsn is used. But don't take my word for it.

@BenThul so it seemed also to me when reading the source, but to me it feels strange, since it can put a strain on the db, affecting the overall performance. Maybe there's an optimization somewhere for this kind of thing (it's only a function), but that's why I've asked the question

What strain? That is, what are you observing in your running system that suggests that running this is causing a problem? Related, what kind of problem is it causing?

@BenThul running a query, e.g. every second, may put a strain on the db. It's not a heavy one, but I'm wondering about that aspect.

Don't wonder - measure. Also, what do you think is the higher strain: figuring out the max lsn (which I think is cached/persisted) or getting all of the changes between the last max and the current max? Even there, don't wonder - measure.

Thanks to Ben Thul for the comments, I was able to solve the doubt.
As linked in the comments, the connector relies on some queries that are being used by the driver during polling operations. The function for getting the latest LSN and comparing it with the one currently stored in Debezium has probably some optimizations. Furthermore, the other queries are used only on need, when data changes (i.e. new LSNs are pushed in the log).
For reference, below the link to the source of the connector  https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/4955244532dac01d9e712723971ce50624d209f1/debezium-connector-sqlserver/src/main/java/io/debezium/connector/sqlserver/SqlServerConnection.java
